# javascript changed my link address in string

Tags: javascript

I have a link from google, and I use this in `iframe` html tag. I want to change a part of this link but I get some error. seems `%20` is the problem in the link. How can I take this link without any change?

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('mapcanvas1').src = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=37.474203,%2049.446669&amp;t=&amp;z=10&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=&amp;output=embed";
</script>
```

Comment: `%20` is just unicode for space, you should be able to just omit it.

Comment: ok, but how can i do that?

Comment: Change `%20` to "space" (the actual space, not the word).

Comment: how do you mean by change a part of this link?

Comment: I want to get location coordinates from database and insert into this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, you are having problems with the encodings in URL. Fix by:

- Changing `%20` to "space" (the actual space, not the word space);
- Changing `&amp;` to `&`;

It then becomes the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById('mapcanvas1').src = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=37.474203,49.446669&t=&z=10&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed"; </script>
```

**Second**, the values of the coordinates can be dealt with the following:

- For new variable in the address, just put `&` at the end and the variable name followed by `=` and the value. Example: `...example.com/?q=...&newVar=value`;
- To change the coordinates, change `q=37.474203,49.446669` to the actual coordinates. Example: `q=" + lat + "," + lon + "` being `lat` and `lon` the coordinates variables for *latitude and longitude*;

It then becomes the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById('mapcanvas1').src = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + lat + "," + lon + "&t=&z=10&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed"; </script>
```

**NOTE**: the first variable in a link address is initiated with `?` and not `&`. Only the second and later ones use `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is encoding the some characters twice, try:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('mapcanvas1').src = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=37.474203,49.446669&t=&z=10&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed";
</script>
```

Comment: @Amirrezazahed In the case of a correct answer mark it as such so other viewers know it's been answered by clicking the checkmark under the vote arrows on the left of the answer. This will also give the answerer their due points :)

Answer (score 0):

`&amp;` is how you encode a `&` for HTML, but you are using it in JavaScript.

You need a literal `&` character and **not** an HTML entity throughout your string.